# copying files to another location from text file

Tags: c#, robocopy

We're working on moving files from one server to another. The last time we did this, we used vb Script. We move around a million files (took several days).

We're looking to speed up the process, as this looks like it's going to be a recurring process with possibly more files to be moved going forward.

**Parameters:**

- Files to move dictated by two text files with multiple lines
- Multiple files will be associated with each line in .txt files
- Will need to search for files with parameters from text files
- Copy the found files over to the new drive

**Here's the idea:**

- Store all parameters into an array
- Loop through the array and find the met parameters using something like this:

  - System.IO.Directory.GetFiles("PATH").Where(s => s.Contains("three"));
- If c# containerizes that search, then copy those files using RoboCopy so we can multithread

**Question:**

- Can this be done?
- If not is there a way to multithread the code in c# to move through this faster?

My experience with c# is what I've learned in the last few days. If you need some of the code I've created already, let me know.

Comment: Something like that should work - you may want to consider `AsParallel()` but without knowing details on how your parameters work, we can't say how to combine the queries.

Comment: Great. Thank you for both the pointer and the confirmation.

Comment: Given the nature of your parameters, I would suggest reversing the searching - do one `GetFiles` and test against each of the parameters rather than scanning the `PATH` over and over (which should be much slower than testing against parameters).

Comment: @NetMage Are you suggesting do a getfiles then for each file in get files test the parameter listed in the text files verses do a getfiles.where(file=>file.contains("text'))?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest reversing the order to minimize the `GetFiles`:

- Store all parameters into an array
- Store all the files on the path:

  ```
  var files = Directory.GetFiles("PATH")
  ```
- Loop through the array and find the met parameters:

  ```
  var ans = parameters.SelectMany(parameter => files.Where(s => s.Contains(parameter)))
                      .Distinct()
                      .ToList();
  ```

  - Then copy those files

Comment: Thank you. I did that. That portion looks to be running very efficiently.